# How to maintain log of incoming and outgoing chat messages of skype, gtalk etc in other android application

Tags: java, android

I am designing application,that should broadcast notification when other IM chat client like skype,gTalk etc in the phone sends or receive chat message.also i want to maintain log of chat messages from  IM chat client like skype,gtalk etc.in my application..
is it possible??..is there any API available for skype and gTalk??
how to do this??
please reply..
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Unless they have explicitly provided documented ContentProviders or Broadcasts what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: there is no public API available for skype..if i want to retrieve data from status bar notification ..how i will do that??.